# How does the If Exists work in TruClient Load Runner 12.55?

Tags: loadrunner

Does the If Exists condition wait till the Object not found timeout setting or it will evaluate the condition immediately on truclient ?

If it wait till the timeout setting, will this be included in Transaction response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "If Exists" step will wait for the object in question to appear.
Once it appears, script flow will resume, entering into If group.
If the object is not found by the time defined as the step's Object Timeout, the If group will be skipped and the next step will be executed (or an Else group, if there is one).

The time spent waiting for the object to appear will be counted in Transaction Response Time, as it indicates the time the application was not ready for interaction.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a way to make the IF condition to be evaluated immediately rather than waiting on TimeOut ? Will this happen if I set the timeout to less value?

Comment: The If condition IS evaluated immediately. In this case, the object is searched-for immediately and then searched for again, until the timeout has passed. Setting a lower timeout will cause the If Exists step to end earlier, if the object if not found.